# How to use a C++ class dll loaded explicitly in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

For exactly the reason mentioned here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/253b8k2c.aspx

> "The application does not know the name of a DLL that it will have to
>   load until run time"

I need to load a dll that doesn't bind its name to the application. That is, **I don't need the application to require "myDll.dll" to work (because in our configuration system, myDll.dll is not named like that)**. However, using *GetProcAddress* for every function doesn't seems like a good idea, specially since it needs the decorated names, and that's error prone.

I was wondering if there's a way to continue using __declspec(dllimport) or something similar without the dll name binding.

My last resort is to create a C interface and a class that uses *GetProcAddress*, but I think there should be a better way.

**Edit:**

I should note that I can edit the .cpp and .h of the library, create a .lib, etc.

I can even (but this is very specific to this application) create an object of the class contained in the dll (we have some hooks for this). However, I can't use the header of my dll class, because then it requires that I load "myDll.dll"

Comment: There is of course a better way, implicit linking.  You have to link the import library of the DLL so that the linker knows where the function resides.  "A DLL that doesn't bind its name to the application" is meaningless, the DLL plays no role in this.  If you don't have an .h file with function declarations and a .lib file that's the import library then GetProcAddress() is your lot.  There is of course a programmer that can help you make this a lot simpler, the odds you will find him here are zero.

Comment: @Hans Then I must me doing something wrong, because after I use myDll.lib, the application requires that my Dll is named myDll.dll (which is not the case).

Comment: Hard to guess where this went wrong.  Have you considered *renaming* the DLL you use to myDll.dll?

Comment: That's not possible. Our configuration file renames the dlls, and I can't modify it.

Comment: Hmm, so you actually *know* why it doesn't work and it is completely obvious to everybody why it doesn't.  There's a pretty good cure for this kind of institutional "can't-do-what-I-should-do" dilemma, you'll find [it here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dumpbin program to list the exported symbols:

```
dumpbin /exports OLDNAME.dll
```

You will get that kind of output:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file OLDNAME.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for OLDNAME.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    529B7ABB time date stamp Sun Dec 01 19:06:51 2013
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00011109 ?MtDlladd@@YAHHH@Z = @ILT+260(?MtDlladd@@YAHHH@Z)

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .idata
        2000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        4000 .text
       10000 .textbss
```

Now create a new text file with the following contents:

```
LIBRARY NEWNAME
EXPORTS
?MtDlladd@@YAHHH@Z
```

Replace NEWNAME with the final name of your problematic DLL.
Under EXPORTS, copy all the function names given by implib, as is.
Name that text file NEWNAME.DEF

Make a new lib file with that DEF file, using `lib`:

```
lib /def:NEWNAME.DEF /OUT:NEWNAME.lib
```

Now you can link with that lib, and your application will require NEWNAME.DLL

Comment: I will give it a try. Is there a way to completely remove the dependency on load time? The thing is, we're not relying on the PATH to load our dlls, but provide the path to the library at run time. To make things worse, there might be other dlls that share the same name. Is... complicated.

Comment: If you use Explicit Linking, you will be able to do whatever you want with DLL's names and locations, but you'll have to LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.

Comment: At the end, this problem was as Hans mentioned: "can't-do-what-I-should-do". We ended doing something completely different, but this deserves to be the right answer